# full height content with scrolling footer

Tags: html, css

I've got the following setup:

header,
content - which needs to be full height of the browser,
and footer

The current setup below is how I want it (when the browser is opened fully). Basically the content div should have 100% height and you simply scroll to view the footer. The amount you scroll is based on the height of the footer. The content will be a simple login form. I've added in a div with a fixed height to demo my issue (The login div could be any height). However the problem is when the browser is resized vertically. This is the tricky bit to explain:

My question is how do I prevent the footer from overlapping the content div? I'd like the footer to snap to the bottom of the content div. As the browser window gets shorter, i'd like the content div to still remain 100% in height. The browser will cut the content div as it gets vertically shorter (which is fine) but I'd like the footer underneath the content div and still want to only be able to scroll to the height of the footer.

I think i'm missing margin-bottom somewhere but not quite sure where. Could someone please help with this issue. Thanks in advance.

the html:

```
<body>


    <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="content">

            <div class="loginPanel">

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        footer, hidden until scrolled
    </div>


</body>
```

the css:

```
html, body {
height:100%;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

.wrapper {
height:100%;
background:orange;
}

.content {
background:grey;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

.footer {
background:purple;
height:200px;
width:100%;
color:#fff;
}

.loginPanel {
width:600px;
height:300px;
background:green;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve what you want with the following:

```css
html, body {
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    position:relative;
}
.wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
.content {
    background:grey;
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}
.footer {
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
}
.loginPanel {
    width:600px;
    height:300px;
    background:green;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="loginPanel"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">footer, hidden until scrolled</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a `margin-bottom` to the `<body>` or `<html>` element; that should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="page-wrap">

  Content!

</div>

<footer class="site-footer">
  I'm the Sticky Footer.
</footer>
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -142px; 
}
.page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  height: 142px; 
}
.site-footer {
  background: orange;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I've forward you a link to what i'm trying to achieve. Sorry if my explanation wasn't very good. In the link below you don't see the footer until you start scrolling. Thanks for you help

http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-full-slider/